# Two implementations for two different Java versions

Tags: java

I'm asked to make a Java app. It is meant to run on a Debian server. The thing is that:

- This server uses Debian 7 (wheezy) which has Java 6 and Java 7
- The server should be updated *soon* to a newer version that will have Java 8

There are many places in the code where using a stream would be great, instead of using a good old for loop. Though, this isn't supported in Java <= 7.

So my question is: is there any way to have two implementations of a class, one for Java <= 7 and one for Java >= 8? The choice would be made at compile time depending on the compiler (JDK 7 would compile the Java7 version and JDK 8 would compile the Java8 version).

*By the way, I'm asking this regardless of the actual problem. It's a question that I find interesting, I know it's something that can be done in Android (to target different API levels) but I'm not sure it's possible in pure Java.*

Thank you in advance

Comment: Its better to work with for loops than creating 2 classes doing the same thing!

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I was asking regardless of the context. Let's say I have one API that is far more efficient (but only works with Java 8) and another one that is not that good at all but compatible with Java 7, is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: Just found this after a quick Google search: https://blog.codefx.org/tools/multi-release-jars-multiple-java-versions/

Comment: Thanks for this! It looks like it exactly fits my need. Too bad that it only works past Java 9 haha

Comment: Until Java 9 you'll need to maintain 2 separate codebases. Depending on the number you could factor out the affected classes and set up your build system to compile twice, including the separate sources as appropriate, and producing the corresponding version dependent artefacts. But to do it dynamically at runtime simply isn't worth the effort (and risk of bugs).

Comment: I'm curious to know how easy the IDE's make it to exploit that multi-release feature.  After all, if the IDE still imposes distinct "projects" per targeted release it's still not very useful.

Comment: Besides I'm wondering can't java8 just be installed on that Wheezy ?

Answer (score 0):

That is theoretically possible but not so simple. You would be well advised to write code in java 7 standard so it would be backwards compatible. However, if you still want to write 2 classes: You will need to write each class in separate project and compile them (each in correct jdk version) to be in different jars. Then you will need to write your own classloader that would load appropriate jar based on your jvm version. I'd definitely say it's not worth it